# Cannot download to local drive when HTML is executed as Apps Script on Google Platform

Tags: html, google-apps-script

The target scenario is that one of my Google sites shall offer a download button via which a user can retrieve a file (hosted on Google Drive) which he/she can then store on the local machine.

To demonstrate the problem, I have a short sequence of code just to show and execute the Download button. When I execute this code locally, the download is possible as planned, even though the download file's origin is on Google Drive. The same code however executed on the Google Site does not work.

```
    Test on local PC
<br>
The link however points to a file on the Google drive
<br>
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMc0xMODNpMUMwM0E/view?usp=sharing

<br>
<br>
<button type="submit" id="download" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMc0xMODNpMUMwM0E/view?usp=sharing')">Download</button>
```

When executed locally the result is as follows:
[image: Scenario when executed locally]

As you can see, when the Download button is clicked the window opens with the blue Download icon. Once this is clicked, I later get the option to store the loaded file (app-debug.apk) on any local or network drive of my machine.

When the same code (just with different explanatory text) is executed in a html file which is called by my apps script, the result is as follows:
[image: executed as apps script]

At first everything looks the same, the file is found and the blue Download button is offered. However when this button is clicked only a blank browser window opens. There is no option to select a location on the local environment.

Is this behavior by design? If so, what is wrong in my understanding and what would be an appropriate method to realize this function also when the page runs in the Google platform?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: huha tried it on chrome, and IE 11. Both offered me the page to download from a gas webapp.

Comment: You might want to check the tutorial made by Google when building a Sites Application - [Part 1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app) and [Part 2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app-part2). This tutorial basically everything you need to know when embedding a script in a Google Sites page. Note that : **This tutorial is no longer maintained — follow the instructions at your own discretion.** Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You could just use a button that links to the link that this site will give you:
[G Docs to Download](https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/)

Comment: Dear Jonathan, I followed your advice and used:  <button type="submit" id="download" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B9P-4EpF1HhMdUgwRlRBN1lmSUU')">Download Link</button>
 instead. However, the result is the same: When executed from local, it allows me to select a local folder for storing it; executed from the GAS, it only offers a blank browser page.